# Forcing a validation step in an Unreasonably Effective RNN

Tags: validation, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Reading through [Andrej Karpathy's 2015 post, "The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks,"](https://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) there's a section where LaTeX code is generated:

> Algebraic Geometry (Latex)
>
> The results above suggest that the model is actually quite good at
>   learning complex syntactic structures. Impressed by these results, my
>   labmate (Justin Johnson) and I decided to push even further into
>   structured territories and got a hold of this book on algebraic
>   stacks/geometry. We downloaded the raw Latex source file (a 16MB file)
>   and trained a multilayer LSTM. **Amazingly, the resulting sampled Latex
>   almost compiles.** We had to step in and fix a few issues manually but
>   then you get plausible looking math, it’s quite astonishing:

(**Emphasis mine**)

What techniques could be used with modern networks to /force/ that any proposed output /did/ compile?

Would you simply run a (slow) compiler process (yikes!) on any output and apply a massive penalty term to something that failed?  A small penalty term?

My questions are:

1. Is there a general term in the literature for this process?  I could imagine other kinds of constraints users might want to add, but something like "general schema validation" seems challenging and not exactly clear without effectively learning a parallel net that black-boxes whatever the schema validation is doing.
2. Is there a Keras/Tensorflow implementation of what (1) is?

Comment: What you have suggested won't work, if you want to penalize each time a compile fails, the model will just perform poorly on the training set as well, The second thing that you can try is coming up with a custom function that just validates if the Code will compile based on the rules of Latex, which might work.

Comment: Thanks.  How would a custom function be better than an actual LaTeX compile step and how would it prevent the problem of performing poorly on the training set as well?